# Make ScrollView scrollable only if it exceeds the height of the window

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

Currently I have a view like this:

```
struct StatsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Test1")
            Text("Test2")
            Text("Test3")
        }
    }
}
```

This renders a view that contains 3 texts inside a scroll view. Whenever I drag any of these texts inside of the window, the view will move because it's scrollable, even if these 3 texts fit in the window and there is remaining space.
What I want to achieve is to only make the `ScrollView` scrollable if its content exceeds the window's height. If not, I want the view to be static and not move.

I've tried to use `GeometryReader` and setting the scroll view's frame to the window width and height, also the same for the content but I continue to have the same behavior. I have also tried setting `minHeight` and `maxHeight` without any luck.

Comment: I don't think scroll view scrolls if its content doesn't exceed screen height by default.  from your description, I think it is bouncing (if it comes back to the initial position after leaving touch). Try setting scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false & scrollView.bounces = false and check if it works

Comment: @MuhammadAli, this is about SwiftUI, which ScrollView does not have either `alwaysBounceHorizontal` or `bounces` like UIScrollView in UIKit, so be attentive next time before commenting so categorical.

Comment: @Asperi At least MuhammedAli pointed out this is bouncing behavior. As such this sounds a bit like a duplicate for [how to disable scrollview bounce in swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799474/how-to-disable-scrollview-bounce-in-swiftui). The accepted answer there has some flaws, so you may want to add your answer there as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a possible approach if a content of scroll view does not require user interaction (as in PO question):

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct StatsView: View {
    @State private var fitInScreen = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {          // container to calculate total height
                    Text("Test1")
                    Text("Test2")
                    Text("Test3")
                    //ForEach(0..<50) { _ in Text("Test") } // uncomment for test
                }
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    // calculate height by consumed background and store in 
                    // view preference
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                        value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height) })
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                 self.fitInScreen = $0 < gp.size.height    // << here !!
            }
            .disabled(self.fitInScreen)              // for iOS <16
            //.scrollDisabled(self.fitInScreen)      // for iOS 16+
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `ViewHeightKey` preference key is taken from [this my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450966/automatically-adjustable-view-height-based-on-text-height-in-swiftui/62451599?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#62451599)

Comment: It seems that disabling the ScrollView also disables all other interactive elements within the ScrollView. Is there a modifier which only disables the scroll capabilities without effecting the content of the ScrollView?

Comment: With SwiftUI, are we now starting to abuse API methods in iOS development to find visual solutions? In this "solution" it should be clearly mentioned that `disabled` disables all controls contained in it. This affects both user interaction and styling (e.g. if there's a Button nested). A solution with GeometryReader, Conditional Views and View Content would be the proper way, imo.

Comment: @Ienny please check my post

Comment: Made it a bit more generic and packet it into this GitHub project: [ScrollViewIfNeeded](https://github.com/dkk/ScrollViewIfNeeded)

Comment: @Daniel Good job, useful package!

Comment: @Daniel Amazing bro, ScrollViewIfNeeded help me so much ^^!

Comment: Instead of `.disabled`, it should be `scrollDisabled`.
scrollDisabled can block scrolling without disabling interaction with child views

Answer (score 35):

For some reason I could not make work any of the above, but it did inspire me find a solution that did in my case. It's not as flexible as others, but could easily be adapted to support both axes of scrolling.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OverflowContentViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var contentOverflow: Bool = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { contentGeometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        contentOverflow = contentGeometry.size.height > geometry.size.height
                    }
                }
            )
            .wrappedInScrollView(when: contentOverflow)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func wrappedInScrollView(when condition: Bool) -> some View {
        if condition {
            ScrollView {
                self
            }
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func scrollOnOverflow() -> some View {
        modifier(OverflowContentViewModifier())
    }
}
```

Usage

```
VStack {
   // Your content
}
.scrollOnOverflow()
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted answer, as it works with views that have interactive elements. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me. The content never became scrollable.

Comment: Great, easy to use solution! I wrapped the `VStack` in a `Group` and applied the modifier there, because my `VStack` had padding, that I wanted to be inside the `ScrollView` and not applied to the `ScrollView` itself. So all in all: `Group { VStack { /* content */ }.padding() }.scrollOnOverflow()`

Comment: Presumably a broken record by now but conditional modifiers (eg if bool { scrollview {self} } else { self }) can result in broken animations and also seem to have an impact on some view refreshing, so use it with care (or even better, spare yourself some debugging nightmares and don't use conditional modifiers at all..)

Answer (score 26):

**Post iOS 16.4:**
You can now use the [scrollBounceBehavior(_:axes:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart/scrollbouncebehavior(_:axes:)) modifier:

```
var body: some View {
   ScrollView {
      // your content
   }
   .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize, axes: [.vertical])
}
```

**Post iOS16:**
I'd have used the pattern matching nature of ViewThatFits:

```
var body: some View {
   ViewThatFits {
      // your content
      ScrollView {
          // same content
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Best pre-iOS 16.4 solution with`ViewThatFits`.  As native as it can get with zero custom code to be maintained.

Answer (score 13):

My solution does not disable content interactivity

```
struct ScrollViewIfNeeded<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content

    @State private var scrollViewSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(shouldScroll ? [.vertical] : []) {
            content().readSize($contentSize)
        }
        .readSize($scrollViewSize)
    }

    private var shouldScroll: Bool {
        scrollViewSize.height <= contentSize.height
    }
}

struct SizeReaderModifier: ViewModifier  {
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color.clear.onAppear() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         size = geometry.size
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

extension View {
    func readSize(_ size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(SizeReaderModifier(size: size))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct StatsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewIfNeeded {
            Text("Test1")
            Text("Test2")
            Text("Test3")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This caused the view to act erratically for me when `shouldScroll` is false. I fixed it by moving the DispatchQueue.main.async block inside an `.onAppear` modifier on `Color.clear`.

Comment: @johnpenning could you please paste your final code?

Comment: @PabloBlanco I updated the answer with the fixed, final code

Answer (score 8):

I've made a more comprehensive component for this problem, that works with all type of axis sets:

**Code**

```swift
struct OverflowScrollView<Content>: View where Content : View {
    
    @State private var axes: Axis.Set
    
    private let showsIndicator: Bool
    
    private let content: Content
    
    init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical, showsIndicators: Bool = true, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._axes = .init(wrappedValue: axes)
        self.showsIndicator = showsIndicators
        self.content = content()
    }

    fileprivate init(scrollView: ScrollView<Content>) {
        self._axes = .init(wrappedValue: scrollView.axes)
        self.showsIndicator = scrollView.showsIndicators
        self.content = scrollView.content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: showsIndicator) {
                content
                    .background(ContentSizeReader())
                    .onPreferenceChange(ContentSizeKey.self) {
                        if $0.height <= geometry.size.height {
                            axes.remove(.vertical)
                        }
                        if $0.width <= geometry.size.width {
                            axes.remove(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct ContentSizeReader: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            Color.clear
                .preference(
                    key: ContentSizeKey.self,
                    value: $0.frame(in: .local).size
                )
        }
    }
}

private struct ContentSizeKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize { .zero }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = CGSize(width: value.width+nextValue().width,
                       height: value.height+nextValue().height)
    }
}

// MARK: - Implementation

extension ScrollView {
    
    public func scrollOnlyOnOverflow() -> some View {
        OverflowScrollView(scrollView: self)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
    Text("Ciao")
}
.scrollOnlyOnOverflow()
```

**Attention**

This code could not work in those situations:

1. Content size change dynamically
2. ScrollView size change dynamically
3. Device orientation change

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/10700672/lorenzo-fiamingo or another developer :] just need help here. Is there a way please to make this solution responds dynamically for when turning on accessibility and increase the font size. I've tried all other solutions on this post and I think yours is the closest. If you turn on accessiblity and increase font to the max then start the app, it will create the scrollbar and will respond dynamically when switched off but not the other way around. Obviously we don't want to disable UI within the scrollView. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Asperi's answer, we can conditionally wrap the view with a `ScrollView` when we know the content is going to overflow. This is an extension to View you can create:

```swift
extension View {
  func useScrollView(
    when condition: Bool,
    showsIndicators: Bool = true
  ) -> AnyView {
    if condition {
      return AnyView(
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
          self
        }
      )
    } else {
      return AnyView(self)
    }
  }
}
```

and in the main view, just check if the view is too long using your logic, perhaps with `GeometryReader` and the background color trick:

```swift
struct StatsView: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Test1")
                Text("Test2")
                Text("Test3")
            }
            .useScrollView(when: <an expression you write to decide if the view fits, maybe using GeometryReader>)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, because I don't have enough reputation, but I wanted to add a comment in the [happymacaron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128009/10968935) answer. The extension worked for me perfectly, and for the Boolean to show or not the scrollView, I used the this code to know the height of the device:

```
///Device screen
var screenDontFitInDevice: Bool {
    UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 700 ? true : false
}
```

So, with this var I can tell if the device height is less than 700, and if its true I want to make the view scrollable so the content can show without any problem.

So wen applying the extension I just do this:

```
struct ForgotPasswordView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Scrollable == \(viewModel.screenDontFitInDevice)")
        }
        .useScrollView(when: viewModel.screenDontFitInDevice, showsIndicators: false)
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466397/11205628)! answer, I created a custom component that covers reported issue

```
private struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}

struct SmartScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var fitInScreen = false
    @State var axes = Axis.Set.vertical
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ScrollView(axes) {
                content()
                    .onAppear {
                        axes = fitInScreen ? [] : .vertical
                    }
                    
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    // calculate height by consumed background and store in
                    // view preference
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                        value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height) })
                
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                 self.fitInScreen = $0 < gp.size.height    // << here !!
            }
            
           
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

usage:

```
var body: some View {
    SmartScrollView {
        Content()
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is the only one that seems to work with on the fly dynamic type settings, while also not changing the layout when the content is not scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

This might help in case you need to listen on changes in font sizes, context changes etc. Simply just change the `viewIndex` to you needed identifier for changes.

This view will inform you about if it's scrolled or not, and also if the original content fits inside the scrollview or if it's scrollable.

Hope it helps someone :)

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct FeedbackScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    
    /// Used to inform the FeedbackScrollView if the view changes (mainly used in 'flows')
    var viewIndex: Double
    /// Notifies if the scrollview is scrolled
    @Binding var scrollViewIsScrolled: Bool
    /// Notifies if the scrollview has overflow in it's content, to indicate if it can scroll or now
    @Binding var scrollViewCanScroll: Bool
    /// The content you want to put into the scrollview.
    @ViewBuilder private let content: () -> Content
    
    public init(
        viewIndex: Double = 0,
        scrollViewIsScrolled: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false),
        scrollViewCanScroll: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.viewIndex = viewIndex
        self._scrollViewIsScrolled = scrollViewIsScrolled
        self._scrollViewCanScroll = scrollViewCanScroll
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                offsetReader
                content()
                    .frame(
                        minHeight: geometry.size.height,
                        alignment: .topLeading
                    )
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { contentGeometry in
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear {
                                    scrollViewCanScroll = contentGeometry.size.height > geometry.size.height
                                }
                                .onChange(of: viewIndex) { _ in
                                    scrollViewCanScroll = contentGeometry.size.height > geometry.size.height
                                }
                        }
                    )
            }
            .dismissKeyboardOnDrag()
            .coordinateSpace(name: "scrollSpace")
            .onPreferenceChange(OffsetPreferenceKey.self, perform: offsetChanged(offset:))
        }
    }
    
    var offsetReader: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .preference(
                    key: OffsetPreferenceKey.self,
                    value: proxy.frame(in: .named("scrollSpace")).minY
                )
        }
        .frame(height: 0)
    }
    
    private func offsetChanged(offset: CGFloat) {
        withAnimation {
            scrollViewIsScrolled = offset < 0
        }
    }
}

private struct OffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {}
}

struct FeedbackScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FeedbackScrollView(
            viewIndex: 0,
            scrollViewIsScrolled: .constant(false),
            scrollViewCanScroll: .constant(true)
        ) { }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
...

@State var scrollViewIsScrolled: Bool
@State var scrollViewCanScroll: Bool

FeedbackScrollView(
   viewIndex: numberOfCompletedSteps,
   scrollViewIsScrolled: $scrollViewIsScrolled,
   scrollViewCanScroll: $scrollViewCanScroll
) {
    // Your (scrollable) content goes here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution allows you to use Button inside:

> Based on @Asperi solution

> **SpecialScrollView:**

```
/// Scrollview disabled if smaller then content view
public struct SpecialScrollView<Content> : View where Content : View {

    let content: Content

    @State private var fitInScreen = false

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        if fitInScreen == true {
            ZStack (alignment: .topLeading) {
                content
                    .background(GeometryReader {
                                    Color.clear.preference(key: SpecialViewHeightKey.self,
                                                           value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)})
                    .fixedSize()
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        else {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                ScrollView {
                    content
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                                        Color.clear.preference(key: SpecialViewHeightKey.self,
                                                               value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)})
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(SpecialViewHeightKey.self) {
                     self.fitInScreen = $0 < gp.size.height
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SpecialViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```

> **USE:**

```
struct SwiftUIView6: View {
        
@State private var fitInScreen = false
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("\(fitInScreen ? "true":"false")")
            SpecialScrollView {
                ExtractedView()
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SwiftUIView6_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView6()
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    @State var text:String = "Text"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {          // container to calculate total height
            Text(text)
                .onTapGesture {text = text == "TextModified" ? "Text":"TextModified"}
            Text(text)
                .onTapGesture {text = text == "TextModified" ? "Text":"TextModified"}
            Text(text)
                .onTapGesture {text = text == "TextModified" ? "Text":"TextModified"}
            Spacer()
            //ForEach(0..<50) { _ in Text(text).onTapGesture {text = text == "TextModified" ? "Text":"TextModified"} } // uncomment for test
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunatly none of the solutions here allow for dynamically responding to when turning on accessibility and increasing the font size on the fly. Hoping there will be a complete solution without disabling the UI within the scrollView.

Answer (score -1):

This might help in case scrolling needs to be disabled depending on some condition. It's possible from iOS 16 onwards:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        // Content
    }
    .scrollDisabled(yourFlag)
}
```