# Two Text inside a ScrollView that Fit to the content of the Texts

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text, swiftui-scrollview

I have two `Text` in a `VStack`. Both texts can grow to an unlimited amount of lines. I want that if the text grows more than the screen I can scroll and see all the content.

Mi first approach:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title)
            Text(subtitle)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.orange)
            .padding(.top, 24)
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)

        Button(buttonTitle) { }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.all, 24)

    }.background(Color.gray)
        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20)
}
```

Result:

[image]

Of course there is no scroll... so I added a ScrollView:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title)
                Text(subtitle)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .padding(.top, 24)
                .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        }

        Button(buttonTitle) { }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.all, 24)

    }.background(Color.gray)
        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 20)
}
```

Result:

[image]

It works! But when the text is not enough to fill the whole height of the screen the `ScrollView` still expands to the whole space available and I want it to wrap the content and "disable" the scrolling capability.

Sample of what I get with little amount of text:

[image]

Sample of what I would like to get with little amount of text:

[image]

So the question is how can I make the `ScrollView` to "wrap" the content instead of expanding to the whole height of the parent `View`?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466397/12299030?

Comment: did you try to set the height on your scroll view?