# Swiftui: check if content fits scrollview without scrolling

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I wonder how to determine if the content inside ScrollView is fully visible without scrolling?

```
ScrollView {

 LazyVStack {
  PlainButton("1")
  PlainButton("2")
  PlainButton("3")
  PlainButton("4")
  PlainButton("5")
  PlainButton("6")
  PlainButton("7")
 }

}
```

I was going to use onAppear/onDisappear to tell if "1" and "7" are visible. Works for "1" as it's always visible from the very beginning... But if "7" is not visible - "onDisappear" event is not called right after load..

UPDATE: replaced VStack with LazyVStack

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466397/12299030?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, i have to use LazyVStack inside of my ScrollView , therefore it doesn't work. Is there any workaround for this case?