# How to fix a list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making an app with Swift and I have a question about lists.

```
// Display the list of the incorrect words
                List {
                    ForEach(arrayToPass, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("・ \(displayeWord[index].word)  : \(displayeWord[index].meaning1) ")
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(10)
                            .bold()
                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 390, height: 400)
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

As shown in the pic attached down below, the list can be scrolled and dragged down, which makes some space above the list. I want to fix the top of the list although the list is scrollable.

That would be appreciated if you could help me out. Thank you.

[image: The list pic]

Comment: You need to show the code have you tried already, also an image of desired view could be very helpful

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Sorry! I totally forgot about the codes. I just added them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s not clear to me how you want to “fix” the list

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Can you see some space above the list? It is happening I scrolled the list. I want to make the list static when there are only a few words in the list if that makes sense.

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting? If you target iOS 16+ or ideally 16.4+, you can use `ViewThatFits` or `scrollViewBehaviour`. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75585180/4667835).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well enough your issue you could do something like this to solve it. Instead of a List you could use a ScrollView:

```
struct ListAnswerView: View {
    
    private var words: [Word] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].compactMap( {
        Word(word: "Answer \($0)", meaning: "Meaning \($0)")
    })
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("You got 100 points")
                    .font(.title.bold())
                
                Text("Here are the words you got wrong")
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom, 100)
                
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0..<words.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("・ \(words[index].word)  : \(words[index].meaning) ")
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .padding(10)
                            .bold()
                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 400)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .background(.white, in: .rect(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
    
}

struct Word: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var word: String
    var meaning: String
}
```

With some Swift magic you can resemble the look of a List without the dragging behavior:
[image: ScrollView like List]

The modifiers I have used are available since iOS 16, so if you need it to be compatible with previous versions od iOS let me know! Tell me if this solution worked for you!

Comment: `words[index]` will crash you need a valid `id` param to the `ForEach` `View` its not a for loop

Comment: It did not crash in my testings. I created a struct that conforms to Identifiable actually. I used words.count since you were using the index inside the for loop.

Comment: I've updated the code to include more details. Without more infos on your behalf it's hard to guess what your specifics are. I built my solution based on the infos I could grasp from your code and what you said. You are using "index" in your Foreach loop, so I'm assuming that is a list of Int numbers that is <= displayeWord.count.

Comment: one way to make it crash is remove the last item in the array

Comment: Well, adjust it for your needs. With the infos you provided I cannot do that much. I don't know your model. You just provided 10 lines of code and no other structs to give us a hint. You want us to guess the rest of your code? Do you know what a minimal reproducible example is? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Give it a read.