# Scrollable responsive text container in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, responsive

I need a text rectangle in SwiftUI where the rectangle wraps tightly to the text, but should there be too much text, it scrolls. Common requirement I'm sure.

I can create a view `TextScrollView` that adopts to the screen size/orientation that offers a scroll view (fig 1), but it hogs too much screen (fig 2). **Or** I can create a view `TextScrollFixView` using the `.fixedSize` modifier (fig 3) that does not hog screen estate, but won't adapt to fit small narrow screens by (fig 4).

[fig 1 TextScrollView - nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuXit.png)

[fig 2 TextScrollView - don't like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsC1N.png)

[fig 3 TextScrollFixView - nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6WnO.png)

[fig 4 TextScrollFixView - don't like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeinZ.png)

My workaround is to use `ViewThatFits` to select the appropriate view, but I'm sure there must be a simpler way of achieving this.

```
Import SwiftUI

struct mainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()                          // Plain top rectangle
                .frame(width: 300, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(.myGreen)
            textRectView()                        // Where the action is
            Rectangle()                          // Plain bottom rectangle
                .frame(width: 300, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(.myGreen)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct verboseTextView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("first line")
            ForEach(1..<20) {  _ in
                Text(verbatim: "The lazy fox")
            }
            Text("last line")
        }
    }
}

struct TextScrollView: View {
var body: some View {
    ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
        verboseTextView()
    }
  }
}

struct TextScrollFixView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
            verboseTextView()
        }
       .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)   // Note the fixedsize statement
    }
}

struct bestFitTextRectView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .vertical) {
            TextScrollFixView()  // of simply use verboseTextView()
            TextScrollView()
        }
    }
}

struct textRectView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            bestFitTextRectView()
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 100)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.Blue))
                .padding()
                .shadow(color: .Cyan, radius: 10)
        }
    }
}
```

I did experiment with `overlay`s and `ZStack`s (rectangles + list view) but I reckon using a rectangular background works best and supports shadows.
How can I achieve this basic framed text requirement more simply?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75585180/560942

Comment: What's stopping you from using `TextEditor`?

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx . I hadn't seen the thread so I tried the solutions there. They were elegant but didn't solve my problem - that dead space is displayed within the text rectangle.

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato . Your suggestion is for editing rather than just displaying and I couldn't see a "disable input" parameter. Nor could I figure how it could be used with complex text, which I'd not included in the VerboseTextView to simplify the examplencode..