# Align views in Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

How do I align the `Color` views in a straight line with the text to the side?

To look like so (text aligned leading):

█  red
█  green
█  blue

Or this (text aligned center):

█    red
█  green
█   blue

Current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorName: Colors = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select color", selection: $colorName) {
            ForEach(Colors.allCases) { color in
                HStack {
                    color.asColor.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    Text(color.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


enum Colors: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case red
    case green
    case blue
    
    var id: String { rawValue }
    var asColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .red:      return .red
        case .green:    return .green
        case .blue:     return .blue
        }
    }
}
```

Result (not aligned properly):

[image: Result]

Without the `Picker`, I found it is possible to use [`alignmentGuide(_:computeValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alignmentguide(_:computevalue:)-330fz) to achieve the result. However, this needs to be in a `Picker`.

Attempt:

```
VStack(alignment: .custom) {
    ForEach(Colors.allCases) { color in
        HStack {
            color.asColor.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .alignmentGuide(.custom) { d in
                    d[.leading]
                }
            
            Text(color.rawValue)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 50)
}

/* ... */

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    struct CustomAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in context: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return context[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
        }
    }
    
    static let custom = HorizontalAlignment(CustomAlignment.self)
}
```

Result of attempt:

[image: Result 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solution is to use dynamic width for labels applied by max calculated one using view preferences.

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 13beta / iOS15

[image: demo]

*Note: the `ViewWidthKey` is taken from my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253241/12299030*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorName: Colors = .red
    @State private var maxWidth = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select color", selection: $colorName) {
            ForEach(Colors.allCases) { color in
                HStack {
                    color.asColor.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text(color.rawValue)
                }
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self, 
                        value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) {
                    self.maxWidth = max($0, maxWidth)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: maxWidth, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should align your text and fix your issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorName: Colors = .red
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select color", selection: $colorName) {
            ForEach(Colors.allCases) { color in
                HStack() {
                    color.asColor.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    Text(color.rawValue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A simple `.frame` modifier will fix these issues, try to frame your text together or use a `Label` if you don't want to complicate things when it comes to pickers or list views.

If you do go forward with this solution try to experiment with the `width` and `height` based on your requirements, and see if you want `.leading`, or `.trailing` in the alignment

Comment: The original edit of my question used `Label`, which I switched because I didn't know how someone might solve the problem. Although this mostly solves the problem, it would be nice to have something centered and uses something like alignment guides so I don't need to hardcode any sizes. In reality I have a lot more items than this, it's just a minimal example. Thank you for answering though! Basically the widest item in the picker would stay, and everything else is aligned to that.

Comment: if you want centered items instead of leading, use frame, what frame does is it will essentially keep the entirety of text within the height * width space, so what I would do is see what the largest color length you have and based on that set the frame size. I don't use alignment guides much cause I don't need them, but maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: Problem is that it should adapt to different font sizes, etc :/

Comment: Added an attempt with `alignmentGuide` which works when not using `Picker` as an example.